# How to show chat list of firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show chat channels in order. Like show that channel first which has recently added a message. Code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.child("dummy").setValue(0);
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot != null)
                {
                    names.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        String name = child.getKey();
                        if(!child.getKey().equals("dummy") && child.getKey().contains(phoneNumber))
                            names.add(name);
                    }

                    peopleAdatper = new PeopleAdatper(getApplicationContext(),names,users);
                    listView.setAdapter(peopleAdatper);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
```

My `ChatMessage` class:

```
ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
chatMessage.setMessageText(messageEditText.getText().toString());
chatMessage.setNo(parentRef);
chatMessage.setName(sharedPreferences.getString("nickname",""));
chatMessage.setDuration(duration);
long time = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
chatMessage.setMessageTime(time);
myRef.push().setValue(chatMessage);
myRef.child(childRef).setValue("new");
```

and database structure is:

```
{
  "0300****644_0333****366" : {
    "-L4b9UHJGuIV311odBXz" : {
      "duration" : "",
      "messageText" : "hel",
      "messageTime" : 0,
      "name" : "Bilal Shahid",
      "no" : "0300****644"
    },
    "0300****644" : "seen",
    "0333****366" : "seen",
    "dummy" : 0
  },
```

Usually firebase show channels in order they created. But i want them to order like we have in simple mobile message app. I have searched a lot about it but didn't found any thing for this scenario. Thank you

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I have added the database structure ..... not exactly the db structure beacuse i can't upload images yet ..... so ithink that you can understand from this ... thanks

Comment: You don't need to add images. Add a part of your JSON file. Export it from Firebase Console.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: What kind of sorting do you want to have?

Comment: Sorting just like we have in our mobile sms app ..... Channels are on top which have recent messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Firebase does not store metadata automatically, you need to do it yourself. To achieve what you what, you need to add a `TIMESTAMP` property for both of your sections, `channels` and `messages`. This will help you sort messages inside a channel according to the date and time of the last message that was received. If you want to sort the channels according to the same rule, then everytime a message is recieved, change the `TIMESTAMP` field of your channel with the `TIMESTAMP` of the last message. In this way, the channels will be also sorted by the date and time of the message that was last received.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I will try your way.

Comment: Ok. And keep me posted.

Comment: I have added the time parameter in both channel and messgae... but when i  write Query query = database.getReference.orderbychild("time").limittolast(20) .... i didn't get what i want ... actually it didn't order the channel

Comment: Just adding the timestamp for both sections and and then quering the data is not enough. As i told you in my answer, you channels will be also ordered when you will change the timestamp of you channel once a new message is received. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: yes when i added the time in new message i also added a time parameter in channel..

Comment: Fair enough, but only adding the timestamp both sections and not keeping them synchronized, will not solve your problem. As I told you in my answer, your channels will be also ordered when you will change the timestamp of you channel once a new message is received. So when a new message is received, change the timpstamp of your channel with the timestamp of your message. Right?

Comment: when a user add new message timestamp is added in message and channel both.

Comment: That's perfect. Then what is the problem?

Comment: but message channels not come in order.... the message channel comes in order on which they are created first

Comment: That means that you are not setting the timestamp correctly when new message is received or you use an incorrect query. Check this two things.

Comment: No ... :(
I have a lot of other work too.... i give it a lot of my time and it just give me a headache..... help me here please.... give some example code according to my given code..

Comment: I cannot code for you. This cannot be done in an answer, I just gave a guidance on how to achieve this. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Query query = database.getReference().orderByChild("time").limitToLast(20) this is the something i found to order the channels but it didn't work

Comment: actually there are many chanels on my firebase database which have not time parameter.... i recently added time parameter.... maybe this is the problem that not all the channels have time parameter ... ?? ..

Comment: Definitely, that is the problem. All channels should have time parameter. If you don't have time parameter, you query does not know how to order them. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yeah ... i think ...now i have to add a time parameter in all the channels .. Thanks brother for your help